# parse rails model field angularjs in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, angularjs

I'm using cloudinary which when it uploads a field (I believe, though I'm not certain) enters a json string into the field of the model/db of my rails app.

In turn it uses that to display the url

I am using angular and parsed the model into json to import it into a ng-init so that I can loop through the rows of the model and display their fields.

the problem is when I get to

as this shows the field as a rails hash...(example)
{"url":"http://path/image.jpg"}

```
<div ng-init="list = <%= @videos %>"></div>

        <input type="text" ng-model="search" style="padding-left:10px;" placeholder="Search videos" >

        <ul>
            <li class="vid-block z-depth-3" ng-repeat="video in list | filter:search">
                <a href="#">


                    <div class="vid-title-text">{{video.title}}</div>
                    <div class="vid-desc-text">{{video.description}}</div>
                    <img src="{{video.video_url}}">

                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

nevermind - I used

angular went ahead and found url when I used the .url and returned the image url

sorted